# PrimeOutput error from server, no error from local

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have this error message when I launch an SSIS from an SQL job :

> "Message Executed as user: LMPI\sqlagent. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   14:00:32  Error: 2015-01-08 14:00:38.04     Code: 0xC0047038
>   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Flat
>   File Source" (396) returned error code 0x80040E21.  The component
>   returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
>   The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the
>   error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure. 
>   End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). 
>   Started:  14:00:32  Finished: 14:00:39  Elapsed:  6.63 seconds.  The
>   package execution failed.  The step failed."

But When I run the same SSIS from my computer everything works fine.

Can anyone help me with that please?

Thanks

Comment: All the data types and lengths are matching

Comment: This:   " There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure. "   Look for more error messages in the output and post them.

Comment: Need more information about your setup. You're using a flat file source. Great, where's the data at? Local or a network location? If network, UNC or mapped drive to access? The LMPI\sqlagent account running sql agent, is that a domain account or local? What permissions does it have? Can it access the file system where the source file lives? How are you invoking the package on the server? Are Credentials involved?

Comment: - There is no other error messages
- The file is in a network location UNC
- sqlagent is a domain account, it's running all the other jobs we have, it has all the necessary accesses
- The package is stored on the DB server and it's called from an SQL job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you run this package on your computer under LMPI\sqlagent account which I deem is the culprit. Most possibly it lacks the write rights to where the file it. 
The remedy is in using a proxy to run the SSIS Package Step in the Agent.
The following article helps set it up: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this even if I tried running the job with my username and I still have the same error.

Comment: Then inspect other messages, they can be below it or above. It could be then a metadata/schema issue